# How to deal with several "ExitCode"s set to "forceReboot" in a WiX bundle?

Tags: wix

The bundle project has two EXE installers, both of which must reboot the computer. The code is as follows:

```
<Chain>
    <ExePackage
        Id="RDRole"
        Cache="no"
        Compressed="yes"
        PerMachine="yes"
        Vital="no"
        SourceFile="Resource\ServerManagerCmd.exe"
        Permanent="yes"
        InstallCommand="-install RDS-RD-Server">

        <ExitCode
            Behavior="forceReboot"/>
    </ExePackage>

    <ExePackage
        Id="DoNetFull"
        Name =".NET Framework 4.0 full runtime"
        Cache="yes"
        Compressed="yes"
        PerMachine="yes"
        Vital="yes"
        SourceFile="Resource\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
        InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
        Permanent="yes">

        <ExitCode
            Behavior="forceReboot"/>
    </ExePackage>
```

How can I make the computer reboot only once if both the `RDRole` and `DoNetFull` get installed?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't currently supported by the Burn engine today. There is a feature request open to create something like a `RollbackBoundary` that says if you need a restart at this point, take it. We could call it a `RestartBoundary`. However, that doesn't exist today.

However, like most things in Burn, you can create the same concept by developing a custom Bootstrapper Application that returns force restart from OnExecutePackageComplete when it noticed a restart is required by previous packages. It's not terribly difficult to implement once you have a custom BA.

Comment: Rob the most frustrating thing about WiX is the simple fact that the use of XML as the specification language, instead of just having a library with an Object oriented API that would allow clean construction of installations, causes all of these "context" issues since actions are interrelated by the schema supported. To this day, I still don't understand why installers can't be simple on Windows. It is the Bane of every developer, and has been for decades, that installers take 10 times as long to create and get right as the application did to start with.

Comment: The WiX Toolset provides an CodeDOM you can code against if you prefer. Installation is naturally very hierarchical (because most of the resources being installed are tree based) and that makes XML quite a natural way of representing the data (as long as angle brackets don't bother you **too** much).

Comment: As for installation complexity, the Windows Installer is powerful and probably more complicated than it should be. However, IMHO, installation pays for the application's sins. If your application is clean, installation should be relatively straight forward. If your application is complex or makes poor decisions, you get to pay for it in installation.

Comment: I was told that a Back Office product asked the user to **"reboot twice"** several times during a huge server install sequence. To this day I wonder what the setups were doing. Scheduling **run-once** stuff that then needs a second reboot? Setting up **services with interdependencies**? **System-wide path settings** that everything depends on - like a compiler? COM files with chained dependencies? Way too complicated - bad design for sure. But in this kind of scenario the **reboot control sequence** is probably the most important feature needed from a bootstrapper.